# IE can't grab XML from YouTube API v2?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, youtube-api, cors

I have been working on a web page that takes a specific YouTube channel's upcoming live events and formats it into a calendar, where you can click a link for each video to embed the player for it. In Firefox and Chrome it runs just fine, but IE can't even get the XML from YouTube using `XMLHttpRequest`. It gives me error SEC7118, and tells me something about requiring CORS.

Any ideas?

EDIT

So as it turns out, MS, with their glorious thought process, thought that `XMLHttpRequest()` wasn't good enough for them for CORS, so they decided to create `XDomainRequest()`, and used that up until IE11, where they eventually got around to supporting CORS for `XMLHttpRequest()`(meaning they acknowledged the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response header).

Unfortunately, as far as I can test at this moment, `XDomainRequest()`, in my current implementation, only works with IE9 and IE10, and requires some messing around to get it to a usable state as an XML DOM object. I suspect it doesn't work in IE8, because I was testing it from `file://`(local test page) rather than `http://`, which is what the API uses.

My code as it stands is(simplified):

```
function XMLCorsRequest(url){ 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
    // Browsers with standard CORS support in XMLHttpRequest(), e.g. Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE 11
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(){
      populateSchedule(xhr.responseXML);
    };
    xhr.open("GET",url,true);

  }
  else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
    // IE v <= 10
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(){
      XDRParse(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.open("GET",url);

  } else {
    // No CORS support at all
    return null;
  }
  xhr.send();
}

function XDRParse(rawXmlAsText) {
  var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = "false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(rawXmlAsText);
  populateSchedule(xmlDoc);
}
```

The function `populateSchedule()` is called once the request is loaded, and an XML DOM object is created. All it does is grab the upcoming live event entry tags, and then sort through them creating a multi-dimensional array with video IDs(the `v` parameter for a YouTube video), start times, descriptions, and statuses, so it can create a table showing all the details.

I also noticed a couple more problems with IE:

It couldn't grab the `innerText` value of a XML DOM object node, so `textContent` was required for it to work across all browsers(that I've tested).

Regular expressions don't work as they are supposed to for time at least.After turning the start date of a YouTube event(which is presented as the date and time in UTC) into a normal Date object, I called it using `toLocaleString()`. I then attempted to slice off the last `:00` which represented the seconds(I didn't need them). Normally, the expression to match it should have just been `/:\d\d(?=\s)/`(replaced with nothing); but because IE is IE, it was somehow using "zeroes" that weren't 0 but were somehow "digits", creating unknown characters between each actual character, and I couldn't check for following characters, so the expression became `/:[^\d]*\d[^\d]*\d[^\s\d:]*\s/`(I just replaced this with a space).

Firefox also does something strange. When `toLocaleString()` is used, rather than stating the date in `mm/dd/yyyy` fashion, it returns the full day of the week, the month, dath of the month followed by a comma, then the year, and then the time as though it would be normally(e.g. Thursday, March 27, 2014 10:00 AM).

These aren't things I need help with, but I figured someone stumbling across this could use my findings.

Comment: can you post the code? also check http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: OK. Sorry for the delay in my response; we had some issues that rose up(for unrelated things), and I wanted to look into this further before I responded. Luckily that link you gave me was a great lead.

I'll make an edit in my post to show what I've done.